# Alamofire/Swift - How to add a boolean header value in request

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I want to create a request in **Alamofire** with headers with boolean values, but the `HTTPHeaders` just accept a dictionary `[String:String]`.

What do I do?

Example of header that what I need:

```
static let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "Content-Type":"application/json",
    "boolValue": true
]
```

Comment: adding 0 or 1 instance of  true/false, Bool in URL encoded parameters encodes as 0 and 1

Comment: I need to add on request header not on URL. Can you give me a example?

Comment: You can also add in header as above @afrodev

Answer (score 0):

To response this,

I create a HTTPHeaders `[String:String]` like this:

```
static let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "Content-Type":"application/json",
    "boolValue": "true"
]
```

I changed my Alamofire request encoder from **URLEncoding.default** to **JSONEncoding.default** like this:

```
let req = Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header)
```

This happens because Alamofire on **URLEnconding** no convert the dictionary [String:String] to primitive values and **JSONEncoding** does.

Comment: U have changed your params, but what if we have to send bool value then have u found any solution?? @afrodev